# "/usr/bin/flameshot gui" throws error: "bash: /usr/bin/flameshot: No such file or directory"

Tags: software-installation, keyboard-shortcuts

To bind the "Print" key (on my keyboard, it is called "prt sc") as a shortcut to my Flameshot app on Linux Mint, I used the guide of the Linux Mint Forum [[SOLVED] How to bind PrtScrn key to Flameshot](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=340886)

But I could not find out where it was installed, and `whereis flameshot` did not find it either.

```
/usr/bin/flameshot gui
```

throws the error:

- when run from the bound "Print" key:
- and when run in the console:

  ```
  bash: /usr/bin/flameshot: No such file or directory
  ```

[image]
*(mind: the screenshot is slightly changed since I put a wrong path after I had fixed it, just to show how it would like)*

How can I bind the "Print" key to Flameshot, so that I can make screenshots also while opening menus, when hovering over items, or any other changing setups?

The Mint Software Manager installed it as the "flatpak" version. I do not know where the installation path of "flatpak" applications is so that I can bind it to the key, and I would not mind installing another version of Flameshot as long as I can bind the "Print" key. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run just the name of the app:

```bash
$ flameshot
Command 'flameshot' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install flameshot
```

although it is installed.

It still is worth a try. After uninstalling ¨Flameshot" with a right-click on the icon in the home menu, and after running

```
 sudo apt install flameshot
```

I can bind flameshot to the "Print" key, on my keyboard, it needs to be "F10" to avoid having to press "Shift" as well.

[image]

I later also added a key binding for "Print" for my external keyboard:

[image]

Works as said in the guide.
Anyone who knows the path for the "flatpak" installer, please answer, whether this is best practice, and then I will accept that anser. It should work with the "flatpak" installed by the Mint Software Manager as well, and that should be the default, I guess.

*(on the other hand, I had this "flatpak" installer also for codium (= vscode), and I also needed to uninstall that after some steps since it took some small steps to set it up, and that scared me away...)*